# How to run two versions of odoo simultaneously?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I want to run openerp 7 and odoo 8 on a single machine simultaneously in windows operating system. I tried with changing port numbers and user name,but it didn't work out. So is there any way to do this?

Comment: I work with two instances odoo in the same machine and I had problems with the cookies. Check [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194543/why-am-i-getting-internal-server-error-with-two-odoo-v8-instances-running-at-t) if you want to know more. But maybe that's not going to happen with two different versions. Creating a new postgres user and changing the ports should be enough as Odedra says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can run two OpenERP/Odoo version in different OS with *--xmlrpc-port=port_number*

```
Where port_number will indicate number.
```

We can also do like that, create two postgres users.

1. openerp
2. odoo

Now create two system users:

1. openerp
2. odoo

Configure OpenERP/Odoo's core module with proper user.

Start your server with *--xmlrpc-port=9999*

You may give any number their. I gave 9999, so i will run in browser like 0.0.0.0:9999

NOTE:

If you don't want to create two postgres user than you may also start server with different port with above example.

Module path will be same but port number is different otherwise it will throw error like *"address is already in use"*

Comment: in configuration file, i changed xmlrpc_port to 9069 and then run as http://localhost:9069 in brower it is saying webpage not available

Comment: please check the track-back. If any back-end error will raise than this type of error throws.

Comment: how to add system user to odoo configuration

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look at [here](http://www.serpentcs.com/serpentcs-how-to-run-2-or-more-openerp-servers-on-same-machine). This is the best possible answer, ignore the version number because its old but it want change your steps so have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run two versions of odoo in two database clusters without using dbfilter parameter. It works for me when running V11, V12 and V13 on the same server (V13 will create error if found V12 database).